# What is the largest (size) solid object ever dropped from an airplane to impact the ground in freefall?

Tags: aviation-history

What is the record for the largest single solid item that has ever been dropped from an airplane at free fall to the ground?

1. Here, "free fall" means falling vertically, or nearly vertically falling allowing some leeway for expected horizontal movement such as the ground speed of the plane doing the drop, winds, or unintended Magnus effect among other things, and allows for normal atmospheric air resistance.
2. The object being dropped should be payload, not part of the vehicle doing the dropping.
3. The object should not be designed with the intent to generate lift. For example, the above mentioned Magnus effect would disqualify if a machine was purposely built to spin with the intention of generating lift. This includes things with wings, parachutes, landing thrusters, etc.
4. The object must have hit the ground in an uncontrolled descent in the past. In other words, satellites in free-fall orbit around the Earth do not count unless they fell to the ground and then got re-launched into orbit again (**unlikely**).
5. Objects that burn up in the atmosphere do not reach the ground as a single solid object, so they do not count unless any possibly remaining fragment that may reach the ground is still the biggest object to be dropped and reach the ground in its destroyed state (**unlikely**).
6. The item *does not* have to have been intentionally dropped. For example, if it were dropped with a parachute, but the parachute failed to deploy, that counts.
7. Bombs easily count as long as they don't have a parachute, thrusters, wings or any other design factor that is intended to generate lift.
8. Last, but not least, "largest" means greatest volume, not heaviest.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94111/discussion-on-question-by-ryan-mortensen-what-is-the-largest-size-solid-object).

Comment: I'm not completely sure I understand point 4, but I suggest rewording it to something like: "The object must have already hit the ground at some point before today. In other words, satellites which are currently, today, in free-fall orbit around the Earth do not count." Or, alternatively, simply "The object must not have been in orbit at any time."

Comment: Given the "aircraft" limitation, I would think some of the "massive ordnance" bombs would be about as close as it comes.  Several of these exceeded 10 tons.  Without that limitation the obvious winner is Theia, in "the big splash" that formed the moon.

Comment: Could you specify whether the shuttle being dropped from the 747 carrying it counts, and how you judicate on the shuttle 'dropping' it's main tank? Both are pretty much the end of the discussion if applicable.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A good candidate here is the US T-12 cloudmaker (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-12_Cloudmaker) at 43,600 lbs.

Comment: All bombs dropped from an aircraft glide. They do not fall straight down and hit the spot directly below the point where they were released.

Comment: That a bomb's trajectory, when dropped from a vehicle with a horizontal velocity, is not simply vertical has nothing to do with flying or gliding. It would demonstrate this behavior in a vacuum. It's just Newton's 1st Law in action.

Comment: @Dancrumb In fact, the effect would be even more pronounced in a vacuum, as there would be no drag to reduce its horizontal velocity in that case. However, dropping it from an airplane could prove quite problematic in a vacuum, as the airplane itself would have no lift (and, unless rocket-powered, no thrust) and would also follow a roughly ballistic trajectory toward the ground.

Comment: @dancrumb This study begs to differ with your conclusions. https://www.academia.edu/4005202/EVALUATION_OF_AERODYNAMIC_DERIVATIVES_OF_Mk82_BOMB_FROM_WIND_TUNNEL_TESTING_AND_SEMI-EMPIRICAL_METHODS

Comment: @reirab I specifically did not mention an airplane. The initial horizontal velocity of the bomb at the point of release is the primary reason it does not land directly below the point where it is released.
Aerodynamical effects will certainly have an effect on the specific spot that it lands, but these are a perturbation on the ballistic trajectory of the bomb due to gravity and the bomb's initial velocity.

Comment: @JuanJimenez if the study begs to differ with Newton's Laws of Motion then I don't care to take the time to read it. If, on the other hand, you're obliquely making the point that more than gravity affects the path of a falling bomb, then I would gladly concede that point, while re-stating that aerodynamic force are not a necessary factor to explain why a bomb does not directly below its point of release.

Comment: @JuanJimenez _Nothing_ dropped from a moving aircraft falls straight down, so I'm not sure what point you're trying to make.

Comment: @DavidRicherby the one you just made  too. Thanks.

Comment: @JuanJimenez I get what you're trying to say, but in order for an object to impact directly below the point it was released it has to either a). Be released from a stationary point (no initial horizontal velocity) or b). Be able to maneuver itself/propel itself back to where it was released (as its momentum will carry it forwards).  Gliding is not the main cause for object to land in a different location than over where they were dropped, though the aerodynamics may change how far that distance is.

Comment: No, gliding is not the main reason, but it does contribute.

Comment: What about an airplane doing a loop and dropping it on the way down side of the loop?

Answer (score 43):

I can't think of anything dropped from an aircraft larger than the US Space Shuttle when it was dropped from a specially modified 747 during the testing phases of development.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94110/discussion-on-answer-by-juan-jimenez-what-is-the-largest-size-solid-object-eve).

Answer (score 34):

If you consider the space shuttle an aircraft its self, [the external tank was dropped after it was depleted and broke up on impact to the Indian ocean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Shuttle_external_tank#Standard_Weight_Tank). The heavy early version weight 58,000 LBS empty and 1.68 Million LBS fully loaded. While not heavier than the shuttle it was volumetrically larger.

Answer (score 26):

If we're counting the [Space Shuttle orbiter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Shuttle_orbiter), then I'd say it's probably that's probably the winner at around 150,000 pounds. As Juan's answer describes, it was dropped from the Shuttle Carrier Aircraft for glide testing before the first shuttle launches. The orbiter 'glides' about as well as the average brick, so this seems like it should count.

Other possible contenders I can think of:

- [Pegasus XL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pegasus_(rocket)), an air-launched rocket. It is dropped from an aircraft, after which point its rocket motor ignites to launch a satellite into orbit. Approximately 51,000 pounds.
- The [Minuteman 1b](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LGM-30_Minuteman) inter-continental ballistic missile. While normally launched from the ground, a test was conducted on 24 October 1974 in which [one was dropped and launched from the cargo bay of a C-5 Galaxy](https://web.archive.org/web/20121018002131/http://www.af.mil/information/heritage/milestones.asp?dec=1970-1980&sd=01%2F01%2F1970&ed=12%2F31%2F1989). According to the USAF, the dropped missile stack weighed 86,000 pounds.
- The absurdly-large Russian fusion bomb RDS-220, better known in the West as "[Tsar Bomba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsar_Bomba)," coming in around 60,000 pounds.

It's also worth noting that all of these may be soon blown out of the water if Stratolaunch Systems gets their way. The [Stratolaunch Carrier Aircraft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scaled_Composites_Stratolaunch) is capable of dropping 550,000 pounds of rocket stack payload. The first test flight of the carrier aircraft has been completed, but it hasn't dropped a payload yet.

Comment: Good answer! I didn't know the Space Shuttle's approach glide ratio is 4.5:1, which is only slightly higher than the model concrete glider featured in MythBusters, at 4:1. And the empty weight of the Space Shuttle is only about 165,000 pounds, so a Stratolaunch mission could easily surpass that by a factor of about three.

Comment: Unfortunately I wouldn't put much faith in Stratolaunch.  They appear to be in much worse financial straits since Paul Allen died; and have cancelled development of an in house rocket in  lieu of only carrying Pegasus XL.  That rocket is extremely expensive for its performance level, so finding any customers is going to be a challenge.

Comment: @DanNeely Yeah, that's why I put the "if" in there. Even before Allen died, it seems like they've been having a lot of trouble finding the right rocket to launch from it.

Comment: Did the Tsar Bomba actually hit ground or was it detonated above?

Comment: @Polygnome It was an air burst, but most of it eventually hit the ground. :)

Answer (score 12):

Not dropped from an aircraft, and was part of the vehicle but Saturn V’s first stage was jettisoned at the weight of more than 360000 lbs or 160000 kgs. On Apollo 11 the mass of the first stage was 363425 lbs when jettisoned. After that, it fell freely to the ocean.

Source: http://apollo11nasa.blogspot.com/2012/07/saturn-v-inert-weight-or-dry-weight-or_22.html?m=1

Comment: Hmm, that's pretty heavy.  May warrant it's own question of what is the heaviest man-made object to fall from space to the ground.

Comment: @RyanMortensen that honour would probably fall to Mir or maybe Skylab.

Comment: And S-1C stage did not fall from space. It was jettisoned at around 61 km, which is high for atmospheric flight but still well below Kármán line (100km). Also, the stack was travelling almost upwards at the time so it went on ballistic trajectory.

Answer (score 3):

The [MOAB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GBU-43/B_MOAB)  prototype was 30 feet long and 40 inches in diameter and hard landed. It seems to qualify, but it is a GBU with gridfins, so not totally a dumb bomb. It has almost the same envelope volume as the T12. You'd need an accurate scan of the two to figure out which had the greater volume.

[image]

I also seem to recall that large seaplanes were developed to carry boats out to bombed naval vessels. These weren't little rafts, these were plank on frame, wooden, ocean capable lifeboats with diesel engines that could be airdropped.

It also sounds like failed air drops could qualify - extraction chute functions normally, Main shoots or pallets fail completely. That has certainly happened a few time.

Several of the D-Day invasion towed gliders suffered catastrophic structural failures while being towed, and became qualifying items as they were jettisoned.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have edited the question to require both "free-fall" and "second use in this fashion" (implying intentional dropping ), the answer is "none".  Things aren't dropped out of airplanes on purpose twice.

Comment: Parachutes are dropped out of airplanes multiple times *on purpose* (in most cases attached to a human).

Comment: There is no requirement for second use, only that the object has impacted the ground at a point in time prior to your answer.  Re-dropping is an optional possibility.

Comment: @RyanMortensen, maxim 11: Everything is air-droppable at least once.

Comment: @RyanMortensen sorry I did not understand "4. The object must have hit the ground in an uncontrolled descent in the past. In other words, satellites in free-fall orbit around the Earth do not count unless they fell to the ground and then got re-launched into orbit again (unlikely)".   I interpreted this as mandatory reuse.  What does this condition mean actually?

Comment: @Harper The condition is intended to exclude objects that have not yet completed their fall to make an impact with the ground such as items in freefall orbit around the Earth that are intended to perpetually remain in orbit.  **Some people were seemingly going out of their way to be kind of silly about supposed points of ambiguity, so I was pressured into adding this.*